# Laravel localize "setlocale(): Argument #1 ($category) must be of type int, Illuminate\Http\Request given" error

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I developed multi language web site in Laravel 10. Everything was working fine, since composer does not support laravel 10 libraries on my server, I created a laravel 9 project and moved only the following folders;

```
/app
/public
/resources
/routes
/composer.json
```

then I did composer install and php artisan optimize, the result was successful. But the problem is; When I access my website, I get the following error:

```
setlocale(): Argument #1 ($category) must be of type int, Illuminate\Http\Request given
```

**/app/Http/Kernel.php :**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        **\App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class**, // <- **locale class is here** 
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    **'setlocale' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,**
];
```

**/app/Http/Middleware/SetLocale.php**

```
class SetLocale {
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }   
}
```

**/routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
})->name('home');
Route::get('/setlang', [Controller::class, 'changeLanguage'])->name('setlang');
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],
    'middleware' => 'setlocale'
],
function () {
    Route::get('/', [Controller::class, 'homeview']);
});
```

Comment: Do you have something `$category`?

Comment: What makes you think that this problem is in any way related to Composer? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @STA I don't have any variables related to $category, it mentions it in the error, I don't get it either

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include the full and exact error message, and your attempts to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is related to the `setlocale()` function in PHP. The `setlocale()` function is used to set the locale information for different aspects of your application, such as date and time formatting, number formatting, and string collation.

To fix this issue, you need to **make changes to the middleware aliases** in the `/app/Http/Kernel.php` file.
Please ensure that you have the following import statements at the top of the `SetLocale` middleware file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Comment: i m changed middleware names and working, thank you